# toList on shapeless HList fails when resulting existential type too complex

Tags: scala, shapeless

Given the following definitions:

```
class R[T]

class A
class B
class C
```

This works:

```
val s1 = new R[A] :: new R[B] :: HNil
val r1 = s1.toList
// r1 of type: List[R[_ >: A with B]]
```

While this does not:

```
val s2 = new R[A] :: new R[B] :: new R[C] :: HNil
val r2 = s2.toList
// could not find implicit value for parameter toList:
// shapeless.ToList[shapeless.::[R[A],
// shapeless.::[R[B],shapeless.::[R[C],shapeless.HNil]]],Lub]
```

Where I expect:

```
// r2 of type: List[R[_ >: A with B with C]]
```

**Pseudo solution:**

Supply implicit yourself:

```
val r3 = s2.toList(ToList.hlistToList[R[A], R[B], ::[R[C], HNil],
                                      R[_ >: A with B with C]])
```

This is of course not a solution, as it eliminates the whole benefit of `HLists` (the `HList` is supplied by a caller together with all necessary implicits).

**Clarification**

I am happy if I get a `List[R[_]]` at the end without the type bounds.

Comment: I believe that you can simply explictly specify the resulting List's element type: s2.toList[R[_ >: A with B with C]]. That's quite an improvment already.

Comment: There is a problem here, which I'll look into. However, I'm not at all convinced that the more precise type (`R[_ >: A with B with C]`) is particularly desirable. Wouldn't it make more sense to have a nominal supertype of `A`, `B`, `C`, etc. and make `R` covariant?

Comment: @RégisJean-Gilles Indeed, and that solves the problem.

Comment: @MilesSabin I actually don't care about the bounds. All I want is `R[_]` as a result. I do not control the type parameters that are used for the R's. Making `R` covariant does solve the problem but seems wrong for what `R` represents in my case. Further, I cannot guarantee that in the future `T` will not appear in contravariant position in `R`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've written ought to Just Work, as-is, producing the precise existential type that you were expecting. It'd be very helpful if you would open a bug against shapeless so that a fix for this doesn't get forgotten for the next release.

In the meantime, if the type you're really after is `List[R[_]]` (which seems more likely to be useful to me) then you can ask for it explicitly in a much simpler way than your workaround,

```
scala> import shapeless._
import shapeless._

scala> class R[T] ; class A ; class B ; class C
defined class R
defined class A
defined class B
defined class C

scala> val s2 = new R[A] :: new R[B] :: new R[C] :: HNil
s2: R[A] :: R[B] :: R[C] :: HNil = R@7a26bc5e :: R@518fdf9 :: R@2bc9e90c :: HNil

scala> s2.toList[R[_]]
res0: List[R[_]] = List(R@7a26bc5e, R@518fdf9, R@2bc9e90c)
```

Given that this less precise type is likely to be more useful in context, you'll want to continue using the explicit element type argument to `toList` even after the bug is fixed, so I consider this to be the right answer rather than a workaround.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This works, as @RégisJean-Gilles pointed out. I will file a bug for this.

Answer (score 0):

I just submitted a [PR](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/pull/97) that fixes this.

Just calling `s2.toList`, without explicitly specifying a type, should return the same type as if you created a (standard) list with the same items and let scalac infer the type of the list for you (that is something like `List[R[_ >: A with B with C]]`).